# How to crawl dynamically generated content?

Tags: javascript, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl a webpage but its source code shows the following code:

```
<span class="play-minute"><%= moment %></span><span class="period"><%= period %></span>
```

How can I get the dynamic values? Are there frameworks to help with this task?

Comment: you can use beautiful soup package from python, its very easy and rich for we scrapping.

Comment: But the beautiful soup doesn't return the value of <%= moment %>

Comment: Probably these kind of data won't be available in webpage. Instead it will be posted from a third part AJAX call which you need to trace out.